# Variable expected error

Tags: java, android-studio

I am trying to make a bot that selects a random joke from an array list, but I seem to get an error that says:

> Variable expected

My code so far is:

```
package com.delta.objects;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by WILLIAM on 8/3/2015.
 */
public class JokeBot extends Bot {

    public ArrayList<Joke> jokesIKnow = null;

    public JokeBot(ArrayList<Joke> jokesIKnow) {
        this.jokesIKnow = jokesIKnow;
    }

    public void tellJoke(){

        Double randomNumDouble = new Double(Math.random() = jokesIKnow.size());
        int randomNum = randomNumDouble.intValue();


    }

    protected void sayJoke(Joke aJoke){
        talk(aJoke.getJokeSetup());
        talk(aJoke.getJokePunchline());
    }
}
```

the error comes up for:

```
Double randomNumDouble = new Double(Math.random() = jokesIKnow.size());
```

Comment: What do you expect that line of code to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Double randomNumDouble = new Double(Math.random() = jokesIKnow.size());
```

That's some very invalid syntax. You can't assign the `return` value of a method (in this case `jokesIKnow.size()` is a method which returns something) to anything except a variable. For example, this is legal:

```
int numberOfJokes = jokesIKnow.size();
```

Here you are trying to assign it to another method. Perhaps you mean to write `Math.random(jokesIKnow.size())` which passes the variable into the random generator.

Comment: Your answer indirectly answered my question. I meant to put * instead of =, so now my code is:

 `Double randomNumDouble = new Double(Math.random() * jokesIKnow.size());`

I can understand the downvote however. That is a messy way to do it when your way is much more simple.